# Why does Orleans use BLOBs for storing/persisting grains instead of using relational model? And potential problems that might cause?

Tags: .net-core, actor, orleans

It is my understanding that while storing a grain in the database, Orleans will serialize the entire object in binary, XML or json format first and then store it in its entirety.

So if I have a `Student` grain with fields like `roll_no`, `name`, `age`, etc, I cannot store it like a relational way with `Student` as a table and `roll_no`, `name`, etc as its columns. And I also can't have `Professor` table which has a `One-To-Many` relationship with `Student` table using foreign keys. Is my understanding correct?

1. If so, then I want to know the reasoning behind it? And won't it cause problems for querying data? Moreover relational way of storing data is a proven way, why change it?
2. Suppose I have a newspaper website. With each news article as my grain. Since the grain is stored as a BLOB, I cannot use free-text-search or other functionality that the database provides. Is that true?
3. Suppose I build my application using Orleans and it has fairly large number of grain classes. Suppose after some time I decide that I don't want to use Orleans anymore. I want to migrate my app to Java/Spring or Python/Django. If I don't use Orleans, I can just use any back-end framework I want since my database is in the relational form and is generally portable.
   But with Orleans, will my database too closely tied to the framework, so that it becomes impossible to switch frameworks in the future?

I am a total noob to the whole actor frameworks so forgive me if any of these questions sound stupid.

Comment: Why do you store grain in database? Why do you need such persistence? You have to store STATE, which is usually has no direct mapping to relational model. Do not compare Data Model with Grains which is computation actor. If you plan to migrate to some Java stuff later - there is not analogue in other technologies, maybe `Dapr`.

Comment: Probably you have to read documentation again. What is `Grain` especially, and for which purpose you need Orleans.

Answer (score 2):

1. Orleans is not meant to be used the same way as traditional applications. If you would want to store the state of a grain in a relational database and create a new table for each grain, that would mean that you would have to create migrations anytime you're adding new properties or adding a new grain. That would nullify the flexibility of Grains.
2. That is true, but Orleans would be better suited for a newspaper application which stores news and identifies them using an Id which would make them easily available to access.
3. Again, Orleans is not meant to be used that way, and that would unfortunately mean that you couldn't reuse the same database created by Orleans.

The Actor Framework is meant for some specific cases, and you should always consider the more traditional way for creating applications first before choosing Orleans. Orleans is meant for cases where you have entities/actors that act on their own, have different actions that they perform, and store/manage their own state.